# Pagination threw single custom post type depending on category: Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, pagination, categories, custom-post-type

I have a Wordpress pagination problem. See I have a website which lists posts within a custom category on a few different pages. Where every page belongs to a category. On every single custom post page template I then have a pagination which moves between other previous and next posts within it's category.

For example:
Custom post type is: Projects
The categories are: Ongoing, previous, journey, and time-journey

Then there are pages displaying those posts. 
Page 1 - Ongoing: Lists Projects within ongoing.
Page 2 - Previous: Lists Projects within previous.
Page 3 - Journey: Lists Projects within journey.
Page 4 - Time-journey: Lists Projects within time-journey.

Then for example; The single page of an ongoing project is supposed to have a pagination that paginate between projects of the category ongoing.

The problem is. Some posts within Projects belong to let's say both Previous + Journey. When this happens the pagination get confused of course of which category it should paginate between.

Have any of you experienced a problem like this before, and come up with a good solution?

I have tried having if-statements determine the category and then doing different things. But I can't get it right. I guess I wan't the site to determine if the single project is within the category Journey to exclude pagination of Previous, and so forth.

Thank you for your time. I hope that a solution to this problem also could help others of you in future projects.

Kind regards,
Alexander

First samle code:

```
  <div class="next"><?php previous_post_link('%link', 'Previous post in category', TRUE); ?></div> <?php if ( in_category( 'pagaende' )) {
    echo '<a class="nav-archive" href="/wordpress/pagaende-projekt#anchor">&nbsp;</a>'; } 
elseif ( in_category( 'tidigare' )) { 
    echo '<a class="nav-archive" href="wordpress/tidigare-projekt#anchor">&nbsp;</a>';}
elseif ( in_category( 11 )) { 
    echo '<a class="nav-archive" href="wordpress/rundvandring#anchor">&nbsp;</a>';}
elseif ( in_category( 12 )) { 
    echo '<a class="nav-archive" href="wordpress/en-tidsresa#anchor">&nbsp;</a>';}
    ?>
   <div class="prev"><?php next_post_link('%link', 'Next post in category', '#anchor', TRUE); ?></div>
```

And developed (Identical but with the possibility to change to pagination links. I have for example tried excluding previous category with the pagination of time-journey. But it didn't work so I have not included it. I hope this makes any sense.

```
<?php 
/* ongoing */ if ( in_category( 'pagaende' )) {
/* Previous post */
echo '<div class="next">';
previous_post_link('%link', 'Previous post in category', TRUE);
echo '</div>';
/* Back to project list button */
echo '<a class="nav-archive" href="/wordpress/pagaende-projekt#anchor">&nbsp;</a>';
/* Next post */
echo '<div class="previous">';
previous_post_link('%link', 'Next post in category', TRUE);
echo '</div>';}

/* previous */
elseif ( in_category( 'tidigare' )) {
/* Previous post */
echo '<div class="next">';
previous_post_link('%link', 'Previous post in category', TRUE);
echo '</div>';
/* Back to project list button */
echo '<a class="nav-archive" href="/wordpress/tidigare-projekt#anchor">&nbsp;</a>';
/* Next post */
echo '<div class="previous">';
previous_post_link('%link', 'Next post in category', TRUE);
echo '</div>';}

/* journey */
elseif ( in_category( 'tidigare' )) {
/* Previous post */
echo '<div class="next">';
previous_post_link('%link', 'Previous post in category', TRUE);
echo '</div>';
/* Back to project list button */
echo '<a class="nav-archive" href="/wordpress/rundvandring#anchor">&nbsp;</a>';
/* Next post */
echo '<div class="previous">';
previous_post_link('%link', 'Next post in category', TRUE);
echo '</div>';}

/* time-journey */
elseif ( in_category( 'tidigare' )) {
/* Previous post */
echo '<div class="next">';
previous_post_link('%link', 'Previous post in category', TRUE);
echo '</div>';
/* Back to project list button */
echo '<a class="nav-archive" href="/wordpress/tidsresa#anchor">&nbsp;</a>';
/* Next post */
echo '<div class="previous">';
previous_post_link('%link', 'Next post in category', TRUE);
echo '</div>';

} ?>
```

Comment: How about a *Sample* code?

Comment: Updated above. Hope it makes any sense of what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by defining the category as a parameter in the url and modifying the 'Next post in category' and 'previous post in category' url link to have that parameter in the end.

Comment: How you have passed the category in url?